# Shadow before image and unshadow on hover

Tags: html, css

Hello I got this image which im trying to make dark and when I hover it i want it to be normal opacity again. This is how far i got:

```css
.man {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.man img {
    width:100%;
}
.man:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:1;
}
.man:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="man">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=64" alt="" />
</div>
```

However its the opposite way around, how do I make it so the image is darker from start and normal on hover, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it, check the answer, First if you want to keep all your style and just want to revert it then invert the opacity use on hover and no hover behave, and second if you just want to use an image to go dark, the use

```
 img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

```css
.man {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.man img {
    width:100%;
}
.man:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:1;
}
.man:hover:after {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="man">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=64" alt="" />
</div>
```

```css
.man {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.man img {
    width:100%;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.man img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.man:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="man">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=64" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: and yes, if this would help you then don't forget to mark as right answer

Comment: thanks for you answer, the first one is the way to go:)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```css
.man {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.man img {
    width:100%;
}
.man:after {
    content:'Here is some text..';
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:1;
}
.man:hover:after {
    opacity:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="man">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=64" alt="" />
</div>
```